# xorg not working with dedicated gpu

Tags: xorg, arch-linux

Yesterday, my xorg was working but it was using integrated graphics. I tried to get nvidia working. Now, when I run `startx`, I get a screen on tty3 which shows the output of the last tty I was in. For example, I hit ctrl+alt+f1, type `startx` and am moved to tty3 where I get a black screen with a solid cursor. If I go back to tty0 I can see the output of startx which shows no errors (besides minor gtk css warning) and a blinking cursor. When I go back to tty3, I see the same thing with a solid cursor.

Info:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Hermes 4.8.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 15 10:14:30 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`.xinitrc`:

```
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

conky &
exec startxfce4
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[  1743.684] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[  1743.684] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1743.684] Build Operating System: Linux 4.5.4-1-ARCH x86_64 
[  1743.684] Current Operating System: Linux Hermes 4.8.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 10 17:22:48 CET 2016 x86_64
[  1743.684] Kernel command line: \vmlinuz-linux ro root=UUID=1d746b96-3184-49ac-a204-0f9deda59c87 pci=nomsi initrd=\initramfs-linux.img
[  1743.684] Build Date: 19 July 2016  05:54:24PM
[  1743.684]  
[  1743.684] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  1743.684]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1743.684] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1743.684] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Nov 15 10:24:19 2016
[  1743.684] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[  1743.684] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1743.684] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[  1743.684] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[  1743.684] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1743.684] (==) No device specified for screen "Screen0".
    Using the first device section listed.
[  1743.684] (**) |   |-->Device "DiscreteNvidia"
[  1743.684] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Screen0".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1743.684] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[  1743.684] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[  1743.684] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1743.684] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1743.684] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1743.684] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1743.684] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[  1743.684]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1743.684] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/
[  1743.684] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1743.684] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[  1743.684] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[  1743.684] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[  1743.684] (II) Loader magic: 0x821d40
[  1743.684] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1743.684]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1743.684]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[  1743.684]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[  1743.684]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[  1743.685] (--) using VT number 7

[  1743.685] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[  1743.686] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[  1743.686] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1743.704] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:191b:1462:115a rev 6, Mem @ 0xdd000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1743.704] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:139b:1462:115a rev 162, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  1743.704] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[  1743.704] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1743.705] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1743.710] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1743.710]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1743.710]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1743.710] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  375.10  Fri Oct 14 10:01:22 PDT 2016
[  1743.710] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  1743.710] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[  1743.710] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1743.710]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1743.710]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1743.710] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  375.10  Fri Oct 14 09:38:17 PDT 2016
[  1743.710] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[  1743.739] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  1743.739] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  1743.739] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  1743.739] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1743.739]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1743.739]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1743.739] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[  1743.739] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[  1743.739] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[  1743.739] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1743.739]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1743.739]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1743.739] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[  1743.739] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[  1743.739] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[  1743.740] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1743.740] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[  1743.740] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1743.740] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  1743.740] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 960M (GM107-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[  1744.067] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[  1744.067] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 82.07.94.00.0e
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
[  1744.067] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[  1744.067] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[  1744.067] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  1744.068] (II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[  1744.068] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[  1744.088] (II) NVIDIA(0): Built-in logo is bigger than the screen.
[  1744.088] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1744.092] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[  1744.092] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[  1744.092] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[  1744.093] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[  1744.093] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[  1744.093] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1744.093] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[  1744.093] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[  1744.093] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[  1744.093] (--) RandR disabled
[  1744.095] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[  1744.095] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[  1744.145] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[  1744.145] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.145] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.145] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.145] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[  1744.146] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1744.146]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.22.0
[  1744.146]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1744.146]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[  1744.146] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  1744.146] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1744.146] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[  1744.146] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.146] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.146] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[  1744.163] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input5/event4"
[  1744.163] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[  1744.163] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.163] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[  1744.163] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event7)
[  1744.163] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.163] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.163] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[  1744.163] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[  1744.163] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[  1744.163] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.164] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.164] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[  1744.186] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input9/event7"
[  1744.186] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[  1744.187] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.187] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[  1744.187] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event8)
[  1744.187] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.187] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.187] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[  1744.187] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[  1744.187] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[  1744.187] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.188] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event8 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.188] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event8 is a keyboard
[  1744.203] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:12/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input10/event8"
[  1744.203] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[  1744.204] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event8 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.204] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event8 is a keyboard
[  1744.205] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event1)
[  1744.205] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.205] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.205] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[  1744.205] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.205] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.205] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  1744.205] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1744.205] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  1744.205] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.206] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.206] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[  1744.223] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input4/event3"
[  1744.223] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[  1744.224] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.224] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[  1744.224] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event2)
[  1744.225] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.225] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.225] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[  1744.225] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[  1744.225] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[  1744.225] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.225] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.225] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[  1744.243] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input3/event2"
[  1744.243] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[  1744.244] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.244] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[  1744.246] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M325 (/dev/input/event9)
[  1744.246] (**) Logitech M325: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[  1744.246] (**) Logitech M325: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[  1744.246] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech M325'
[  1744.246] (**) Logitech M325: always reports core events
[  1744.246] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[  1744.246] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.246] (II) input device 'Logitech M325', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  1744.247] (II) Device 'Logitech M325' set to 600 DPI
[  1744.247] (II) input device 'Logitech M325', /dev/input/event9 is a pointer caps
[  1744.293] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0004/0003:046D:400A.0005/input/input11/event9"
[  1744.293] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech M325" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[  1744.293] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1744.293] (**) Logitech M325: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1744.293] (**) Logitech M325: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1744.293] (**) Logitech M325: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1744.294] (II) input device 'Logitech M325', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  1744.294] (II) Device 'Logitech M325' set to 600 DPI
[  1744.294] (II) input device 'Logitech M325', /dev/input/event9 is a pointer caps
[  1744.295] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M325 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  1744.295] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.295] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.296] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event11)
[  1744.296] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.296] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.296] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event12)
[  1744.296] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.296] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.297] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event13)
[  1744.297] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.297] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.297] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event14)
[  1744.297] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.297] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.298] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event15)
[  1744.298] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.298] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.299] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[  1744.299] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.299] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.299] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[  1744.299] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[  1744.299] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[  1744.299] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.299] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.299] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[  1744.343] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[  1744.343] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[  1744.344] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.344] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[  1744.345] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event10)
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[  1744.345] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[  1744.345] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[  1744.345] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1744.345]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.8.99
[  1744.345]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1744.345]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[  1744.345] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  1744.345] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[  1744.383] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: ignoring touch events for semi-multitouch device
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1472 - 5706 (res 44)
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1408 - 4800 (res 65)
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right double triple
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  1744.383] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  1744.423] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7/event10"
[  1744.423] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[  1744.423] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[  1744.423] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[  1744.423] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.037
[  1744.423] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  1744.423] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[  1744.423] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1744.423] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1744.423] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  1744.424] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[  1744.424] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[  1744.425] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event5)
[  1744.425] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.425] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.426] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MSI WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event6)
[  1744.426] (**) MSI WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.426] (**) MSI WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.426] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MSI WMI hotkeys'
[  1744.426] (**) MSI WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[  1744.426] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[  1744.426] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.426] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.426] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[  1744.443] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input8/event6"
[  1744.443] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MSI WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[  1744.444] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.444] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.709] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.736] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Deleting GPU-0
[  1744.807] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.10  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-09)  Fri Oct 14 11:11:07 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

#Section "Files"
#EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
   Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
#    VendorName     "Unknown"
#    ModelName      "Unknown"
#    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
#    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
#    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 960M"
    BusID      "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
       Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Because modern Xorg can configure itself, the first thing to try when things aren't working well is almost always to move /etc/X11/xorg.conf out of the way. Don't delete it, but do rename it or move it to a different directory so you can easily get it back. If that gets you usable graphics, then you can try adding things back piecemeal to identify the part that causes things to break.

Comment: I tried that too. No good.

Comment: You tried *what,* exactly? Starting Xorg with no configuration file present? Adding things back to it piecemeal? We aren't mindreaders; please be as specific as you can about what you did, what you did not, what the expected results were, and what the actual results were. [Edit] your question to include additional detail, as comments are intended to be ephemeral.

Comment: I did rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf and startx. I also tried it with different sections commented. I will add more detail lager, on my phone right now.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling THANK YOU, I was trying to set up my xorg.conf file to use a single GPU with two installed (to save the other for computation).  I moved xorg.conf out of the way after two hours of failed efforts, and, bam, the auto-configure worked perfectly.